# How can I display Hindi language in my JLabel Swing component?

Tags: java, swing, encoding

```
 void display(){
      fr = new JFrame("Resource App");
      JLabel name = new JLabel("one=नमस्ते");
      JTextField txtname = new JTextField(10);

      fr.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      fr.setSize(500,500);
      fr.setVisible(true);

      fr.add(name);
      fr.add(txtname);
 }
```

this code showing me an error:

```
unmappable character for encoding cp1252
```

Comment: Try changing encoding of your project to **UTF-8**. **cp1252** is default encoding.